# Cannot log in to mysql using root

Tags: mysql

So I'm setting up mysql for the first time.

I read somewhere that I have to run this

```
mysql -u root -p
```

To log in as root, in order to be able to create tables/databases using the mysql command line.

When I run this, I get prompted for a password - I hit enter (I thought the default password was blank).

I get this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What's going on?

Comment: try without the -p flag, if not your going to have to skip grants https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) I get that error

Comment: I'm going to be that guy and say try running it with elevated permissions (sudo)

Comment: wait, so in that page, I tried running the kill - I get this message 

cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/psanker-mbpr15.sv.splunk.com.pid: Permission denied
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Comment: As indicated by your /usr/local/ prefix, you're probably not using a packaged version of MySQL. In that case the root password was probably asked for while installing, and if you're not the one who provided it, you need to follow @exussum's suggestion. You must own the process or be superuser to kill it (and probably access the data as well, so start/stop both as superuser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fresh installation of MySql you should be able to issue the following command and it should allow your connection.

```
xyz@ubuntu$  mysql -u root mysql
```

You then should set the root password and then create a user with the correct level of access.

look [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-connecting.html) for help connecting.

Comment: I get acces denied when running that

Comment: Not sure how you installed MySQL, but this always works to get you logged on as long as the root password is not set.